# Passing A Path Variable To A Controller With Spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-social

I am using spring to create an App that links with facebook. When The app is launched it redirects you to a sign in page.  After you click the log in button it redirects you to the homepage. What i want to do is that when the log in button is clicked it redirects you to the homepage and adds a unique number at the end. Whenever i launch my app i am getting an HTTP Status 404  error. I can not figure out what the problem is. EDIT I am using Spring Social Quickstart, the only modifications i made the program were the ones below

**Sign In Page**

```
    <%@ page session="false" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sign In</title>
        </head>
        <body>
<c:set var="rand"><%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 2) %></c:set>
            <form action="<c:url value="/signin/facebook/${rand}" />" method="POST">
                <button type="submit">Sign in with Facebook</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email,publish_stream,offline_access" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Home Page**

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<c:url value="/signout" />">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
        <p>${number}</p>
    <h3>Your Facebook Friends</h3>
    <ul>
    <c:forEach items="${friends}" var="friend">
        <li><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<c:out value="${friend.id}"/>/picture" align="middle"/><c:out value="${friend.name}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Home Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{rand}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@PathVariable("rand") String rand, Model model) throws IOException {

           List<Reference> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriends();
           FacebookProfile profile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
           String userID = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getId();
           model.addAttribute("friends", friends);
           String accessToken = connectionRepository.getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).createData().getAccessToken();
            System.out.println(accessToken);
        return "home";
    }
```

Comment: Which url is giving you a 404 and what is its corresponding handler method?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/my-app/ is giving me the error. Do i have to have a controller that handles just "/" requests?? The controller above is the only controller i have

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you should have a controller method that handles `/` by rendering the view that represents your login page.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Base URL of your application and does your controller have a root URL too? This `<c:url value="/signin/facebook/${rand}" />` line of code will produce something along the lines of `http://localhost:8080/yourAppname/signin/facebook/12342354665`.

Depending on configuration and other annotations you should change `@RequestMapping(value = "/{rand}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/signin/facebook/{rand}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. Your current mapping (depending on controller annotations) just serves root level URLs.

Have you got logging enabled? You should be able to see the failed mapping in your log.

Comment: When i change my controller to just handle "/" requests the app loads to the log in page and loads to, 
http://localhost:8080/my-app/signin, and then when i click the sign in button page it loads to  http://localhost:8080/my-app/#_=_. The signin/facebook is nowehre in the URL which im a little confused about

Comment: So, guessing, you have a project called my-app building to my-app.war that you are dropping in the applications folder of your webserver? The root context is then /my-app/. You then either have a welcome file (index.jsp?) that is forwarding to your login page, or maybe you have some configuration (spring-security?) that is detecting that the user is not logged in and forwarding on your behalf. Without worrying about what happens when you click the button, what is the generated markup (page source)?

Comment: Well, at its most simple and least useful, right click on the page in the browser and select "View Page Source" I think all browsers have that. However if you're going to do much web development I would recommend getting familiar with Firebug, or the developer tools available on your browser of choice.

Comment: when i view page source it shows nothing more than what i posted above.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience of Spring Social, but internally it will have a controller that is handling the `/signin/facebook` URL, you have added an additional component to the path which it presumably isn't configured to understand (it isn't, to see source Google FacebookSigninController). Being Java you can always extend that class though and add your own controller to handle your additional functionality.

Comment: The only controller that they supply you with is 
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String home(Model model)

Comment: No. They supply you the controller I just referenced, have you used Maven before? Your pom file references a number of jars, one of them (<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId><artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId><version>${org.springframework.social.facebook-version}</version></dependency>) contains the Facebook controller.